# Classes and threading in iOS: viewModel scenario

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, thread-safety, closures

I´m following an `MVVM` architecture, so I have a `viewController` that holds a reference to its `viewModel` like this:

```
lazy private var viewModel: MyViewModel = {
    return MyViewModel()
}()
```

Such viewModel is initialized within the `viewDidLoad()` method this way:

```
private func initViewModel() {
    viewModel.onModelChange = { [unowned self] () in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    viewModel.getData()
}
```

Where `getData()` viewModel's method calls another object to perform a networking async task to retrieve the data to be displayed by the viewController:

```
func getData() {
    guard let url = ServiceAPI.getServiceUrl() else {
        return
    }

    dataProvider.getData(url: url, completion: {[weak self] (result, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                self?.model = [MyCustomModel]()
            } else {
                if let result = result {
                    self?.total = result.data.total
                    self?.processFetchedData(items: result.data.items)
                } else {
                    self?.model = [MyCustomModel]()
                }
            }
    })
}
```

Regarding threading, the scenario is: the viewModel is initialized by the viewController and bound to it in the `main` thread. The viewModel is asked to call a networking object (`dataProvider`), also initialized in the `main` thread. `dataProvider` calls also from the `main` thread an `URLSessionDataTask` to retrieve the data needed. The data task is supposed to perform asynchronoulsy in a thread different from `main`. Once finished, its completionHandler is also executed in a thread different from `main`. There is where I update the viewModel (see code snippet above). Then, as the model in the viewModel is being observed, an `onModelChange` closure is executed in the viewController, where I update a tableView with the data. Since this operation is UI related, I do it in the `main` thread (see also code snippet above).

Question is: this seems to work, but is it actually correct/safe to update the `viewModel` in a thread different from `main`? It was created in `main` thread. May this be a potential issue?

`viewModel` is a class, and the `model` it holds is an array of `MyCustomModel` that are structs.